# Open Graph music.song usage

Tags: integration, facebook-opengraph

I want to make use of Music support in FB Open Graph documented at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/music/

I am not sure if Facebook is hiding this page from 3rd party developers or not but I believe it is [not linked](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=google%20backlink&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&source=hp&q=link%3ahttp%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fopengraph%2Fmusic&pbx=1&oq=link%3ahttp%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fopengraph%2Fmusic&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1977l1977l3l2107l1l1l0l0l0l0l105l105l0.1l1l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=51c0baa5191488cb&biw=1280&bih=599) from anywhere.

I want to use `music.song` object defined in http://ogp.me/ but when I create an action in Dev App and type `song` or `music` as object type, no suggestions show up.

Should I create my own `song` object and will facebook be approving that? Or is there a way to use `music.song` if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook Open Graph Music is only available to whitelisted partners at this time.

You are able to create your own music actions and objects, but you maybe won't benefit from all FB music UI elements (for example the music play button?)

Comment: I see, thanks. Do you know how long does it take to get an action approved on the average?